# Blender baking textures

Tags: baking

I've been having problems baking textures in blender. i'm using 2.97 because i'm trying to export to Xplane. this is the artifacts i'm getting on my textures and i cannot figure out why. what am i doing wrong?[image]

Comment: This appears to be overlapping faces. Try hiding your object (h) to see if there is something under it that would conflict with it.

Comment: that actualy helped alot thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This happens when there are two or more faces overlapping. You can fix this by,

1. Using the keyboard shortcut "h", hide the object you want to be there, and
2. If there is anything underneath that is conflicting with your object, you can delete it by hitting delete in Object mode or delete it in Edit mode with face-select.